# Shell.js async build: wait until meteor is listening to open meteor shell, run command, exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, meteor

My goal is to do the following steps in my "bundle" process to export an electron app:

1. open meteor directory
2. run meteor
3. when meteor is listening, open the meteor shell
4. pass the "electrify" command to meteor shell
5. when electrify build is complete, return.

So far, I have the following

```
require('shelljs/make');
require('shelljs/global');
var path = require('path');

target.all = function () {
  target.bundle();
}

target.bundle = function () {
  console.log('Building for architecture: ' + process.platform + platform.arch);
  var meteorPath = path.join(__dirname, 'meteor');
  cd(meteorPath);

  // this runs for a while, make it asyncronous
  var meteorCommand = exec('meteor', { async: true });
  meteorCommand.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    // ???
  });
}
```

This yields expected output to `stdout`.

```
Building for: darwinx64
[[[[[ ~/Code/test/meteor-test ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Babel active on file extensions: es6.js, es6, jsx
I20150728-10:06:05.899(-4)? electrify:  installing electrified dependencies
I20150728-10:06:07.005(-4)? electrify:  launching electron
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

However, I am facing a problem... meteor has a startup process and needs to be running before I can use `meteor shell`, which is the final step where it says "App running at:".

How can I wait for this event to happen before opening the meteor shell?